# Cannot drop collection in mongodb with two dashes in the name

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection I created using mongoimport tool from a file. The problem is I had a typo in my command. Now I ended up with a collection that has two dashes in them.
mycollection--file (do not forget the space before the dashes) Now mongodb wont let me drop the collection. db.mycollection--file.drop() It will get SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier.
It is not just drop but find or anyway to interact with the collection will get that syntax error. But it does get listed in the db, if you do show collections.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe this will work for you:

```
db["mycollection--file"].drop()
```

The square brackets with quotation marks syntax is useful for collection names that have characters in their names that interfere will normal shell commands.

UPDATE:

I've added, queried and then deleted from this collection name in my own mongodb database:

```
 var x = {first:1}
 db["mycollection--file"].save(x)
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 1,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("53d96289aa812bcf293121df")
})
  db["mycollection--file"].find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d96289aa812bcf293121df"), "first" : 1 }
  db["mycollection--file"].drop()
true
```

Comment: I tried your solution and getting SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier. I even added . after the db to see if that was the case bu I got also SyntaxError.

Comment: Hmm strange, I am keep getting Unexpected token [

Comment: can you add your command exactly as run (copy and paste it) along with the error message to your question?

Comment: Sorry I missed one important thing out of your query. The double quotes. It works. Thanks for the solution.